# Append release timestamp to helm template name

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm struggling with finding a way to include the [Release.Time](https://docs.helm.sh/chart_template_guide/#built-in-objects) builtin as part of a helm name.

If I just include it as:
`name: {{ template "myapp.name" . }}-{{ .Release.Time }}`

Dry run shows this:
`name: myapp-seconds:1534946206 nanos:143228281`

It seems like this is a *timestamp.Timestamp object or something because `{{ .Release.Time | trimPrefix "seconds:" | trunc 10 }}` outputs `wrong type for value; expected string; got *timestamp.Timestamp`

I can hack the string parsing by doing: `{{ .Release.Time | toString | trimPrefix "seconds:" | trunc 10 }}`, but it seems like I should be able to call something on the Timestamp object to get the seconds. Is anyone aware of where the docs are for this? I can't find any reference to it at https://godoc.org/github.com/Masterminds/sprig.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To format timestamp, you can use `date FORMAT TIME` from Sprig doc. And because `.Release.Time` got removed in Helm 3, you have to use `now` instead:

```
{{ now | date "20060102150405" }}
```

Refer the format options: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format

But having timestamp in the name is not good idea because of upgrades.

Comment: Hear you on not using the timestamp in the name, but I'm not actually using this for the name of a webapp - its actually for the name of a chart that only deploys a one-off job after install to run a specific performance test against the stack.

Comment: For people who are not familiar like I was, Helm is written in Go lang, hence why he is pointing to Go docs.  The strange "20060102150405" is actually the time format to use, Go seems to base their time formatting on this sample date "Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006" so you just need to rewrite that date however you want it to be formatted.  At least that's my understanding...

Comment: @KillerKode For a long time date formatting has always been hard to remember ( minutes is lower or uppercase `m` ? How many letters? It changes among languages etc), so Go simply decided to give up and to choose a formatting method that would force you to look the documentation up for every single time you format a date, ensuring you end up with correct formatting... genius /s

Answer (score 1):

In my case, by adding the following annotation I was able to achieve this, I am also using helmfile as the wrapper of my helm templates.

```
annotations:
   deploymentTime: {{ now | date "2006-01-02T15:04:05" }}
```