# Is it possible to pass the current datetime in a kubernetes yaml env setting?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I want to use the time that a pod is deployed as an environment variable within the pod.
I cannot seem to make this work though. Anybody have an example on how to do this or maybe some pointers?

Comment: Downward API doesn't have this. Perhaps you're able to pass from helm `{{ now | date "20060102150405" }}`, or `$(date)-$(uptime)` with parsing from the shell.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51983330/923620

Answer (score 1):

If you are using simple pods, then this solution won't work for you. Because pod's env field becomes immutable once created.

But if you are using managed pods ( i.e. deployment, statefulset etc), you can use `kubectl set env` command to update environment variables.

```sh
$ kubectl get deployment nginx-deployment -o=jsonpath='{.metadata.creationTimestamp}'
2020-10-07T13:24:49Z

$ kubectl set env deployment/nginx-deployment CREATIONTIME=$(kubectl get deployment nginx-deployment -o=jsonpath='{.metadata.creationTimestamp}')
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment env updated

$ kubectl exec -it nginx-deployment-7657f96b7f-6w8lf -- env
... ... ...
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=nginx-deployment-7657f96b7f-6w8lf
NGINX_VERSION=1.15.4-1~stretch
NJS_VERSION=1.15.4.0.2.4-1~stretch
CREATIONTIME=2020-10-07T13:24:49Z
... ... ...
```

Deployment file I used - [Link](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/nginx-deployment.yaml)

Comment: I'm working with Deployments, and what want is something like 

~
          - name: MY_POD_STARTTIME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.creationTime
~
Something that updates everytime a pod or deployment is updated
Sorry not being clear. Your example gives me hope that it's possible though.

Comment: @KarimTawfik That's not possible. One thing you can do, implement kubernetes client, and read the value from inside the pod. This is how, you will be always updated.

Answer (score 0):

just out of curiosity, why do you want to do this? The state of all kubernetes objects is stored in etcd and can be accessed via the k8s API.

````
  availableReplicas: 2
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2020-09-22T09:40:02Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2020-09-22T09:42:02Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "nginx-demo-5f4b9dd57d" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  - lastTransitionTime: "2020-09-23T12:57:46Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2020-09-23T12:57:46Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available```
````

Comment: We wanted to export logging from each deployment to a shared location and creating folders based on DeploymentName and Creation/Update datetime